# why a single Java char variable can represent more than 65535 characters?

Tags: java, unicode, char

char in Java is 2 bytes, you can get its range by running below code:

```
System.out.println((Character.MIN_VALUE + 0) + "<char<" + (Character.MAX_VALUE + 0));
```

it's 0~65535

but I am confused that we can convert a integer value (>65535, like 70000) to char, and print it:

```
   char testChar = (char) 70000;
    char testChar2 = (char) 280388456;
    System.out.println(testChar);   //prints ᅰ
    System.out.println(testChar2);  //prints 捨
```

but why?

Comment: Similar: `byte b = (byte) 1000000;`. What do you think that does? (Test it!)

Comment: Review the concept of [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Answer (score 2):

The `280388456` literal exceeds the `char` range and in the context of the `char` type it's actually `25448` (because `280388456 % 65536 = 25448`). Which seems to be the *index* of `捨`. Same goes for the other character.